# How to reuse postmant tests and script?

Tags: javascript, postman

Currently, I have code saved in two requests in order to hydrate my environment vars with tests and scripts.

[functions to reuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2sv7.png)
[tests to resuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNdrL.png)

In the resquest called: 'Scripts to pre requests' —> I have added functions to reuse in other pre requests scripts.

In the request called:'Load common test' —> I have added tests to reuse in other requests tests.

What I have not been able to solve is to hydrate my environment vars without making the POST request that I am sending (totally unnecessary request to oauth)

Another solution would be to directly hydrate the environment var from the console:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG7Y6.png)

But it is not comfortable to write the code there and I have not found another way to load code to reuse it.

What is the right way to solve it?

EDIT:
add snippets of the code in plain text:

```
// functions no reuse
var generate_phone = () => {
    return '0' + _.random(91000000, 99999999);
}

pm.environment.set("generate_phone", generate_phone.toString());

var generate_document = () => {
    return _.random(1000000, 10000000);
}

pm.environment.set("generate_document", generate_document.toString());
```

```
// test to reuse
var admin_profile_test = () => {
    
    pm.test("check admin id", function(){
        pm.expect(data.id).to.equal(parseInt(pm.environment.get("admin_id"))); 
    })

    pm.test("check admin name", function(){
        pm.expect(data._embedded.profile.name).to.equal(pm.environment.get("admin_name")); 
    })

    pm.test("check admin lastName", function(){
        pm.expect(data._embedded.profile.lastName).to.equal(pm.environment.get("admin_last_name")); 
    })

    pm.test("check admin document", function(){
        pm.expect(data._embedded.profile.document).to.equal(pm.environment.get("admin_document")); 
    })

    pm.test("check admin email", function(){
        pm.expect(data._embedded.profile.email).to.equal(pm.environment.get("admin_email")); 
    })

    pm.test("check admin phone", function(){
        pm.expect(data._embedded.profile.phone).to.equal(pm.environment.get("admin_phone")); 
    })
}

pm.environment.set("admin_profile_test", admin_profile_test.toString());
```

I keep the images to show where I currently locate this code.

Comment: please post code as plain text, screenshots of code are prohibited, use screenshots for diagrams and something that cannot be transformed to plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman scripts, variables etc can be defined in collection level also:

click the inverted hamburger after clicking the collection folder and then select edit collection :

[image]

Here you can define your tests and pre-requisite scripts :

[image]

This will run before each request and test

so you can right any logic to skip the pre-requisite when you don't want example pm.request.name != "somethem" { then }

Also you can modify everything in prerequsite script so if you don't want to do post you can change the method from prerequsite as

```
pm.reqeust.method="GET"
```

This will change method to get before sending the request